# Scite Autorun f5 suddenly stopped working

Tags: scite

I use scite text editor to run my code. f5 has been working fine and I've been autorunning program after program in the side window, but suddenly... it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

The **Tools** > **Go** menu item effect is configured with the `command.*` settings in the SciTE properties file. Refer to the [documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html) for the details (search for `command.go` in the page).

The **Go** menu is configured separately for each file pattern. Default configuration is in the `<lang>.properties` file in the SciTE install directory. For example, Python configuration in `python.properties` looks like this:

```
command.go.*.py=pythonw -u "$(FileNameExt)"
command.go.subsystem.*.py=1
command.go.*.pyw=pythonw -u "$(FileNameExt)"
```

This can be overridden in either of these files:

- `SciTEUser.properties` — user properties, resides in the user home directory (user profile directory on Windows)
- `SciTE.properties` — local properties, resides in the same directory as the opened file

You should check what is the configuration for the file pattern in question, and find out if the specified command is actually available on your system.